# Reload a div with full function like before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jstl

I have a div with function report, delete comment button, and a report modal inside and also including jstl foreach to get data from servlet to show a list of comment in div. Here is a part of my code:

```
<div class="comment-list" id="comment-div">
<c:forEach items="${commentList}" var="items">
    <div class="media-body">               
        <input type="hidden" id="commentUserId" name="commentUserId" value="${items.accountId.accountId}"/>
        <h4 id="commentUsername" class="media-heading">${items.accountId.userName}
            <small><i>Posted on ${items.time}</i></small>
        </h4>
        <p id="show-comment">${items.content}</p>                                    
        <a id="${items.commentId}" name="btnReportComment" class="btn btn-report">Report</a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="reportModalComment" role="dialog">
            <!-- report modal content -->
        </div>
        <c:if test="${sessionScope.user.userName==items.accountId.userName}"><a id="${items.commentId}" name="btnDeleteComment" 
        class="btn btn-delete" rel="2" style="margin-left: 20px">Delete</a></c:if>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

I use ajax to post a comment and when I click on the post button it call an ajax function when it success I want it to reload the comment list with function such as delete comment and report comment working.
I did use `$('#comment-div').load(location.href + " #comment-div");` it did reload the div but only the text and data, and there wasn't anything happen when I clicked on the report button or delete button.
Can anyone help me with this

edited:
here is my delete button function:

```
function deleteComment(){
$('a[name=btnDeleteComment]').click(function(){
    var commentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var currentRow = $(this).parent().parent();            
    if (userId == null || userId == '') {
        swal("Request Failed!", "You need to login first!", "warning");
    } else {                                
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this comment!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-primary",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",                                
            }).then( function (result){
                if(result.value){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "UserDeleteComment",
                        data:{commentId: commentId},
                        success: function(resultData){
                            swal("Done!","Your comment has been deleted!", "success");
                            currentRow.remove()
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
                            }
                    })
                }
            })
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you want to do when you click on report and delete button? Where do you defined the click events for those buttons?

Comment: I put them in the same page but in different function and they also have ajax inside. with report button it calls a report modal, and delete button it delete that comment

Comment: Where are you invoking the deleteComment function? I do not see it in your code. The event will be registered only when deleteComment function is invoked

Comment: I tried to invoke deleteComment function inside the ajax which I use to reload the div but it stay the same too. Sorry because my code in this situation is quite long so that I didn't post them in here

Comment: Make sure that the deleteComment function is invoked. Add console.log('invoked') statement inside the function and see if this gets printed to the console

Comment: well it seems that after `$('#comment-div').load(location.href + " #comment-div","");` nothing is invoked

Comment: add a callback function on success of load that will trigger this function and make sure that the event listeners are attached. Check http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: thanks a lot I did it. I put a callback function when the ajax success

Comment: Great! What I would recommend is attach the event listener once at the beginning of your code so that it is executed only once. If you attach event listeners in your callback, every time callback is executed, it will attach additional event listeners so same event will be triggered multiple times